# How do I double underline my TLabel text in delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, underline, tlabel, delphi-12-athens

How can I have a double underline for my labels?

So basically I want two lines at the bottom of the text instead of one. How can this be achieved?

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to replicate. Look at the double underline on the "Contact" text:

[image: double underline]

Comment: No font has double underlines. You will have to subclass the Label an draw it manually.

Comment: @AmigoJack I think you misread my question. I'm for looking for a dotted underline. I need a double underline. I'm busy porting one of our websites to Delphi to be an app and they have double underlines for a lot of link hovers. I will update my question with a screenshot to make it clearer.

Comment: The "_like_" part was a fictional example. Your question nowhere reflects wanting to be an FMX app, and native Windows GUI doesn't provide that to begin with. Websites aren't OS GUIs and vice versa. Or have you ever experienced a ListView in a website? Likewise you cannot expect _everything_ to be possible _anywhere_.

Comment: @AmigoJack Apologies. It is an FMX app I am making.

Answer (score 4):

If FMX is involved, you can easily use a personal style.
Something like that
[image]
should do the trick
[image]

Warning : if multi-os put the style in the "default" style collection.

Todo : to take in charge the label width, find style resource 'underlines' and modify margins. Advantage, with the same resource you can change color, change to only one side etc.

In the same way, and without involving styles, you can just add a TRectangle child of TLabel (less funny)